# Tag removal request: soho

Tags: discussion

This tag exists: [soho](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/soho).  Nothing asked in this tag will ever be on topic (and there is only one question in it that isn't either already closed or about to be).  Assuredly it should be abolished?

Comment: The SO part would be...

Comment: I don't really understand what's wrong with soho ?

Comment: I agree with @Iain ... this stuff is legit.  At many SMBs, the sysadmins are also tech support for the owners home and/or small branch offices.

Answer (score 5):

There are currently 13 questions tagged with [soho](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/soho) - I don't see any singletons.

Feel free to untag them.  The tag will be eaten by the grues if left empty in the darkness long enough :-)

Comment: Oh, my bad.  There is but one unanswered question, and indeed 13 questions.

Answer (score 4):

I see absolutely nothing wrong with the SOHO tag. It's a standard term and while the Home Office portion will almost likely be off topic, the Small Office portion could be very much on topic following the standard provisions that the person who is asking is an IT Professional.

Depending on the business, offices in the SOHO category do employ IT Professionals; whether in a full time roll or on a consultancy / outsourced basis. And, additionally, it's not unreasonable to imagine differing requirements for a SOHO vs an Enterprise. That doesn't have to mean crap or cheap, just different!

Comment: I think a better tag choice nowadays at least here on SF would be "smb".

Comment: @TheCleaner: Except we already use [tag:smb] for smb.

Comment: @Iain - Sure...I was referring to the idea that people don't really say "SOHO" anymore when referring to small businesses in the industry.  Most simply use smb at this point.  So if the person is asking themselves "do I use the tag soho or smb?" my vote is smb as soho is so 90s at this point.

Comment: @TheCleaner: ah right.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Destroy it.